# Apache 2.2 not loading PHP 5.5 module

Tags: php, apache

There are several questions about this out there, but I have exhausted all fixes and this still doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 7 OS (stupid, I know).

Basically I downloaded PHP 5.2.5 and installed with VC6 (there were some issues with VC9 and up not working with Apache 2.2). I edited the php.ini file to have the following additions:

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext/"

extension = php5apache2_2.dll
extension = php5ts.dll
```

I then added the php5apache2_2.dll and php5ts.dll files into the C:/php/ext/ directory. These did not come with the PHP download...I had to find them at random places online. Could that be an issue?

The first extension is the PHP module for Apache 2.2. The next one is something I found on a couple of blog posts that sometimes isn't there and needs to be added for PHP to work with Apache.

In the Apache 2.2 httpd.conf file, I added:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/ext/php5apache2_2.dll"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml

PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

These are all in the appropriate places, etc. I also set the DirectoryIndex to include index.php

Yes, everything is at the right path/in the right folder.

When I restart Apache, it will never restart unless I comment out the PHPIniDir line. The error log I get is:

```
Invalid command 'PHPIniDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in        the server configuration
```

I'm starting to get a bit lost with all of the supposed "fixes" out there and am afraid of getting in over my head and screwing up my computer (some of the suggestions involve pasting stuff in the system32 folder, etc.).

Can anyone help??

Answer (score -1):

Delete last slash from below line:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

Comment: Hmm, tried that and also tried it with and without the extra "/" on "C:/php/ext" in the php.ini file. Apache still won't start. Although Apache is no longer throwing that error, so that's fixed at least!